# jQuery and HTML5 canvas that actively mirrors part of the screen

Tags: jquery, html, css, canvas, mirror

Working on a photo site that will involve reflections on a glass dock. It's pretty slick.

Instead of using CSS3's box-reflect attribute, I'd like to build a canvas layer into the doc that simply flips whatever's above it and has a gradient mask. There are several reasons for it:

- Browser compatibility (Chrome has a box-reflect bug that's killing me)
- Nitpicking artificial physics... when over the edge of the dock, i only want the reflection on the dock

I've looked around online and seen a lot of resources for plugins that build a canvas element for each image you run through- but none of that will work for me.

Ideally, I have some jQuery that copies all the pixels in the area above the dock and flips it upsidedown, then runs on some events I'll predefine (such as whenever an image in the slide show is moved in).

Has anyone seen a resource on this already? Am I crazy and missing a better way? Thanks for your help!

Here's a screenshot for a little eye candy. Everything on the page besides the image is CSS.

http://cloud.dhut.ch/image/0F1i2T0p3i3M

Comment: `jQuery` has almost no tools that would help with this.

Comment: maybe not a prebuilt plugin- but jquery is certainly able to mirror an element to a canvas.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to consider mobile support I would suggest you stick with CSS properties as they will work better than canvas drawing. If on the other hand, you want to support browsers you can create reflections by using the canvas.

The canvas solution is hard. Period. There's no shortcut for making a reflection out of one or a series of images. Here are the basic steps I would take to make the canvas reflections.

1. Iterate over all images you are displaying at a given time.
2. [Draw](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/canvas_drawimage.asp) each image on a hidden canvas.
3. Get [the image data](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/canvas_getimagedata.asp) from the entire canvas, after you draw all images at the same baseline.
4. Iterate and flip the image data using simple for iterations over the pixels.
5. For each pixel row of the image data starting from the top one, reduce the opacity by changing the alpha value of each pixel by a degree. This will create the gradient fade out effect.
6. Put the image data into the reflection canvas.

Each time you change one image from the scene, you need to redraw this. Each time you move (if you have a scrollbar) you have to update the reflection.

This is really costly from the performance point of view.

Having css reflections will be hardware accelerated, it will work out of the box, and when browser will support it completely it will be really smooth.

In my opinion, the canvas approach is overkill.